# I am getting error at this part in EDIT.php and Update.php mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Tags: php

```
EDIT.PHP
<?php 

//error_reporting(0);
include("DB.php");
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$id=$_GET['id'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM hrmsinfo WHERE emp_id='$id'";
$sqll=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
while($profile=mysqli_fetch_array($link,$sqll))
{
$username=$profile['emp_name'];
$usermail=$profile['emp_email'];
$userdob=$profile['emp_dob'];
$usermobile=$profile['emp_phno'];
$useraddress=$profile['emp_address'];
$userproof=$profile['emp_proof'];
?>

<div class="display">
      <form action="UPDATE.php" method="post" name="insertform">

<p>
       <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">Name:</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="ename" placeholder="Enter Name" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" id="inputid"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
</p>

<p>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">EMAIL:</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="eemail" placeholder="Enter Email" value="<?php echo $usermail; ?>" id="inputid"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
</p>

<p>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3">Date Of Birth:</div>
                      <div class="col-xs-5">
                        <div class="input-group date">
                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                          <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                            </div>
                        <input type="date" class="form-control pull-right" name="edateofbirth" value="<?php echo $userdob; ?>" id="inputid">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
</p>






<p>
      <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="row"> 
                    <div class="col-xs-3">Mobile Number:</div>
                    <div class="col-xs-5">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Mobile" name="emobile" value="<?php echo $usermobile; ?>" id="inputid">
                    </div>
                  </div>
      </div>
</p>

<p>   
              <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="row"> 
                    <div class="col-xs-3">Address:</div>
                      <div class="col-xs-5"> 
                      <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Enter Address"  name="epresentaddress" value="<?php echo $useraddress; ?>" id="inputid"></textarea>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
</p>



    <p>
      <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="row"> 
                    <div class="col-xs-3">Proof:</div>
                     <div class="col-xs-5"> 
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Proof"  name="edrivinglicense" value="<?php echo $userproof; ?>" id="inputid">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
    </p>


    <p>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row"> 
          <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-5">
              <input type="submit" name="eupdate" value="Update" id="inputid1" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </p>

  </form>

</div>

<?php } } ?>
```

UPDATE.PHP

```
<?php 
include('DB.php');
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
  $id=$_GET['id'];
  if(isset($_POST['update']))
  {
  $name=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST["ename"]);
  $email=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST["eemail"]);
  $enpassword=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST["epassword"]);
  $dateofbirth=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST["edateofbirth"]);
  $mobile=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST["emobile"]);
  $presentaddress=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST["eaddress"]);
  $drivinglicense=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST["edrivinglicense"]);

 $updated=mysqli_query("UPDATE `hrmsinfo` SET `emp_name`=[$name],`emp_email`=[$email],`emp_password`=[$enpassword],`emp_dob`=[$dateofbirth],`emp_phno`=[$mobile],`emp_address`=[$presentaddress],`emp_proof`=[$drivinglicense] WHERE emp_id='$id'");
  if($result = mysqli_query($link, $updated))
  {
  $msg="Successfully Updated!!";
  header('Location:VIEW.php');
  }
  else
  {
  $msg="Unsucessfull!!";
  }
}
}  //update ends here
?>
```

MY code keeps popping me error like this:-

> mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

what is wrong with this where am i wrong when i remove id it works can i get the id as parameter call for edit and update help me with this

Comment: `while($profile=mysqli_fetch_array($sqll))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because of the line:-

`while($profile=mysqli_fetch_array($link,$sqll)){`

Here you need to pass the `Query-result-set object` only.
So change it to:-

```
$sqll=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
while($profile=mysqli_fetch_array($sqll)){
```

Comment: Once i get result from edit.php and when i am editing the content and updating its totally blank could some help me out where i am stuck

Comment: your edit.php line helped me and i got the output but when i am editing the    edited form and when i try to update the details to update.php its not working its redirecting me to update.php with a completely blank information

Comment: @JinamShah  if the answer helpful to you then you can mark it as an accepted answer. Thanks

Comment: @JinamShah  glad to help you :):)

Comment: my concerned is update.php is showing completely blank page once i update all information from edit.php and when i click update button its completely blank

Comment: @JinamShah  use like this :- $updated=mysqli_query("UPDATE `hrmsinfo` SET `emp_name`=$name,`emp_email`=$email,`emp_password`=$enpassword,`emp_dob`=$dateofbirth,`emp_phno`=$mobile,`emp_address`=$presentaddress,`emp_proof`=$drivinglicense WHERE emp_id='$id'");

Comment: i tried that its not working some where am frozen with my code i updated form